# Where can I see Tile Notification errors in the Event log?

Tags: windows-8, event-log

I am having some issues with a Windows 8 app and Tile Notifications. I've got them working but sometimes after a few days or more the tile stops updating.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/hh465403.aspx

> You can use the Event Log to check for errors when your tile
>   notification does not display. Look for events involving your tile
>   notification in the Event Viewer under Applications and Services Logs
>
> > Microsoft > Windows > Immersive-Shell > Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI > Operational.

The documentation mentions the Event log, but when I look that node does not exist on my machine. Am assuming it was moved and documentation not updated. Where can I see Tile Notification errors in the Event log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the TWinUI operational logs have been moved to the following Event Log path:

> Microsoft > Windows > Apps > Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI > Operational.

Comment: Thanks. If it had teeth, it'd bite me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this issue out.  I'll be sure to let the right folks know so that the documentation is updated.